# Отслеживание нажатий клавиш

Tags: python

В терминале работает скрипт, программа спрашивает да или нет. Сейчас я делаю ввод при помощи `a = input()` это долго т.к. приходится после каждого выбора нажимать `enter`
Можно ли отслеживать нажатия стрелок вправо/влево и на базе этого делать выбор?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# pip install keyboard
import keyboard

result = keyboard.read_key()
if 'left' in result:
    print('left key')
elif 'right' in result:
    print('right key')
else:
    print('error key!')
```